# Google BigQuery Dimensions SQL Multiple Grids

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grid, dimensions

how would you select multiple grids in the example below instead of just one under "WHERE":

```
SELECT
    sdg_code,
    sdg_name,
    "grid.5170.3" as grid,
    year,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) as pubs,
    ROUND(AVG(fcr), 1) as fcr,
    ROUND(EXP(AVG(LOG(GREATEST(fcr, 1)))), 1) as fcr_geomean,
    ROUND(sum(AltWithScore), 1) as altmetric
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            p.id,
            year,
            if(p.altmetrics.score > 0, 1, 0) as AltWithScore,
            cat_sdg.code as sdg_code,
            cat_sdg.name as sdg_name,
            p.metrics.field_citation_ratio as fcr,
            p.altmetrics.score as altmetric_score,
            row_number() over(partition by p.id, cat_sdg.code) as rn
        FROM
            dimensions - ai.data_analytics.publications p,
            UNNEST(category_sdg.full) cat_sdg
        WHERE
            year >= 2011
            AND year <= 2020
            AND "grid.5170.3" in UNNEST(research_orgs)
    )
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY
    sdg_code,
    sdg_name,
    year
ORDER BY year asc
```

What needs to be changed:

It currently only runs for 1 organisation (GRID), I would like it to run for 11 organisations.
The org is identified with an ID called a “GRID”, it looks like this:
"grid.5170.3"

I want my new code to take 10 org IDs more. Need to use these 10:
grid.5254.6, grid.7048.b, grid.5117.2, grid.10825.3e, grid.4655.2, grid.11702.35, grid.154185.c, grid.475435.4, grid.7143.1, grid.27530.33

And add a column with the org name; currently there is only a column with the org.

Thanks, new to this whole thing.

Comment: not clear what exactly the logic you are looking for. provide some example along with expected output - or at least just be more specific on desired logic

Comment: Hi, just updated my question with an examples i tried and failed with, maybe they would explain better what i am trying to do.

Comment: obviously, those are not working examples. but please provide more details on what logic you are looking for. are both grids needs to be in the record to qualify? or just any of two?

Comment: Both. There are 11 different grids, i want all of them to be in the output results.

Comment: still not clear  - read my first comment then

Comment: I updated the full question and the code with what i need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `WHERE year >= 2011 AND year <= 2020 AND "grid.5170.3" in UNNEST(research_orgs)` use below

```
WHERE year >= 2011 AND year <= 2020 
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM UNNEST(research_orgs) grid 
  WHERE grid IN ('grid.5170.3', 'grid.5254.6', 'grid.7048.b', 'grid.5117.2', 'grid.10825.3e', 'grid.4655.2', 'grid.11702.35', 'grid.154185.c', 'grid.475435.4', 'grid.7143.1', 'grid.27530.33')
)
```

Comment: What about "grid.5170.3" as grid," part? Leave it just as that?

Comment: you should include all grids that you need into that list - so just add it inside the list if I missed it :o) - I just added it in the answer :o)

Comment: So just add it in an array such as "grid.5170.3, grid.5254.6, etc" as grid under sdg_name? That was what i meant. On the top of the code. It only lists grid.5170.3 and no others.

Comment: I answered your very original question that was focused on issue with `where` clause and how to expand it to work with multiple grids - `"grid.5170.3" in UNNEST(research_orgs)` . You then quite changed the question and now it is even more ambiguous than it was initially - I recommend you to rollback this question to its initial stated and post new question with those "new" details so I(we) will be able to answer! When you post the new question - please [provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: see also [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)